# Activity completion based on minimum grade with overrides

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

My question is related to Moodle bug MDL-51220 (https://tracker.moodle.org/browse/MDL-51220). This bug was introduced in Moodle 2.8 and I'm using Moodle 2.9. With activity completion turned on and requiring that a student receive a certain minimum grade, the activity is not marked complete if the instructor overrides the activity grade (or the grade of a question in a quiz). Many of my activities are using activity completion based on minimum grades. After one-on-one visits with students to review their activities I end up overriding their grades. Yet they get stuck because the activity does not get marked as complete after overriding their grade.

I'd like to get this working in my Moodle instance. This may be too broad of a question but is there a way to programmatically mark an activity as completed when there is a grade override? I'm hoping it's as simple as calling a function in the Moodle libraries but I don't know where to start.

I have tried calling the web service core_grades_update_grades. I get a status code 0, meaning it worked. But this does not appear to update activity completion for the activity I specify when calling the web service.